# Vertical align text inside dynamic height div

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I want to vertically align text inside a div which is dynamic height say 10% of page for example, but without using the well-known "table method". Can this be achieved with pure CSS?

[image]

Piece of code:

HTML:

```
<div class="post-details-wrapper">
    <div class="post-details-h">
        Post Details
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
post-details-h {
background-color: green;
height:5%;
width:100%;
}
```

In this particular case the goal is to vertically align the text of "post-details-h" div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach is to use display:table stuff. But if you don't want to use it, you can try something like this:

```
<div class="post-details-wrapper">
    <div class="post-details-h">
        <span>Post Details</span>
    </div>
</div>

.post-details-wrapper {
    height:350px;
    background:red;
}
.post-details-h {
    background-color: green;
    height:10%;
    width:100%;
}
.post-details-h:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.post-details-h span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Just add span so you can center taht element inside .post-details-h.

You can check in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5k8ucvf8/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

use `display: flex` + `align-items: center`

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.post-details-h{
    background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; 
}
```

```html
<div class="post-details-wrapper">
    <div class="post-details-h">
        <span>Post Details</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice workaround but there is cross-browser compatibility issue. Works perfectly with Chrome and Firefox but in Safari it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v0oex9py/).  The way that I know how to do it does involve two classes, like how you did it.

```
.post-details-h {
    line-height: 200px;
    width:100%;
    vertical-align: center;
}

.post-details-wrapper {
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: But in this case the height is fixed

Comment: Yes that is true.  I know that you can use `line-height` like this `line-height: 500%;`, but that is a terrible hack and I wouldn't recommend it.  Perhaps if I played around with the fiddle more I could figure something out.